# SplitArgument on colon doesn't work under expl3 syntax

Tags: expl3, xparse, catcodes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\TestA{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{%
  \Example #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\TestB{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{
  \Example #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\DeclareDocumentCommand\Example{mm}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item #1
  \item #2
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
\TestA{one : two}
\TestB{one : two}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: well it works but it is splitting on a letter colon which you don't have in the main part of the document, you want a non-letter (catcode 12) colon

Comment: Don't use `\ExplSyntaxOn`; that's all.

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately this example is *very* minimal; I've already got two levels of indirection with these arguments `:)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought as much. I even had a guess at the problem in the draft, but I opted to nix it because I'm still pretty sure I barely know what I'm talking about `:)` I suppose this isn't fixable without introducing another layer of pass-the-buck? Is there a way to specify the category code as `\SplitArgument` sees it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way for coping with this is to use the celebrated `\lowercase` trick (but note that it uses a `\tex_...:D` function, so it should be avoided;  if possible, opt for the second version):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `: }
\tex_lowercase:D {
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\TestB{>{\SplitArgument{1}{?}}m}
}{
  \Example #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Another way is using the `\begingroup\edef\x` trick:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\group_begin:
\use:x{
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\exp_not:N\TestB{>{\SplitArgument{1}{\tl_to_str:n { : } }}m}
}{
  \Example #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `: }
\tex_lowercase:D {
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\TestA{>{\SplitArgument{1}{?}}m}
}{
  \Example #1
 }

\group_begin:
\use:x{
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\exp_not:N\TestB{>{\SplitArgument{1}{\tl_to_str:n { : } }}m}
}{
  \Example #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareDocumentCommand\Example{mm}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item #1
  \item #2
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
\TestA{one : two}
\TestB{one : two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it makes no sense to use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` if an argument is processed with `\SplitArgument`.

The problem presents also for the underscore, but this is a bit harder, because `_` usually has category code 8.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `: }
\char_set_catcode_math_subscript:n { `? }
\tex_lowercase:D {
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\TestB{>{\SplitArgument{1}{?}}m}
}{
  <code for the definition
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Accepting to clean up my questions, but I'd like to note that I think this case should be handled in `xparse` in a perfect world.

Comment: @SeanAllred Raise the question on the LaTeX3 mailing list. The problem holds also for `_`. Maybe the argument to `\SplitArgument` can be “normalized” with the help of `\tl_replace_all:Nnn`

Comment: That was also my thought---there are a lot of tools in `expl3` now that could be used to effect this.  I'll raise it tonight if I can; I just felt like I needed to note this here.  Not sure why.  (I'm going through old, unaccepted questions of mine.)