# \SplitArgument with underscore

Tags: xparse

Is there a way to use `\SplitArgument` macro with the `_` sign? The following example don't works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \testone }{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m }{ \frac#1 }
\NewDocumentCommand{ \testtwo }{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{_}}m }{ \frac#1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\testone{x-y}$ and $\testtwo{x_y}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It works if you eliminate the `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, it works in this case. But I need to use it in a LaTeX3 package and in this last case something goes wrong.

Comment: You can still you `expl3` pacakge, just add `\ExplSyntaxOff` _before_ those two macro definitions and add a `\ExplSyntaxOn` _after_ the definitions.  I think that is the simplest solution.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I don't understand your comment :-( . Anyway, I found this [egreg's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197390/splitargument-on-colon-doesnt-work-under-expl3-syntax#comment470957_197391) and the relative question. Sorry for the duplicate :-(

Comment: @ddg I added the workaround to my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197390/splitargument-on-colon-doesnt-work-under-expl3-syntax so we can close this one as duplicate: it's better to keep information about similar cases in the same place. However you got my upvote.