# SplitArgument on [semi-]colon doesn't work under expl3 syntax (revisited)

Tags: expl3, xparse, arguments

I tried the two solutions of the [original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197390/splitargument-on-colon-doesnt-work-under-expl3-syntax), didn't work. `-NoValue-` spoils the output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_foo:nnn
{%
  (#1)(#2)(#3)%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}
{>{\SplitArgument{3}{;}}mm}
{
  \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2]
 }

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197390/splitargument-on-colon-doesnt-work-under-expl3-syntax#comment457616_197390

 \group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `; }
\tex_lowercase:D {
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\Qux{>{\SplitArgument{3}{?}}mm}
}{
  \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2]
 }

\group_begin:
\use:x{
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand\exp_not:N\Blah{>{\SplitArgument{3}{\tl_to_str:n { ; } }}mm}
}{
  \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2]
 }


 \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% WANTED: (a,b)(c,d)(e)[f]

\Foo{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\Qux{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\Blah{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

But this works:

```
 \NewDocumentCommand{\Baz}
{>{\SplitList{;}}mm}
{
  \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2]
 }
```

Maybe check the list has 3 elements in it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the first argument of `\SplitArgument`. This first argument gives the maximum number of *separator tokens* in the input, not items. Since you want to have three items, two separators are needed, not three. So, just replace the `\SplitArgument{3}{...}` with `\SplitArgument{2}{...}`.

By the way, the complexities of the [original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197390/splitargument-on-colon-doesnt-work-under-expl3-syntax) were needed because `:` has category code 11 (letter) after `\ExplSyntaxOn` and normally 12 (other) after `\ExplSyntaxOff`, so that TeX doesn't treat them as the same characters. However, this is not the case for `;`, therefore these complexities are not needed, at least in your MWE, where `;` has catcode 12 (other) all along. This is why `\Foo` works as well as `\Qux` and `\Blah` in the fixed example.

Also, typical end-of-line percent signs are not needed under `\ExplSyntaxOn` régime, since spaces are ignored. Finally, I applied formatting conformant to the `xparse` manual.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_foo:nnn
  {
    (#1)(#2)(#3)
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \Foo { >{ \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m m }
  {
    \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2]
  }

\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `; }
\tex_lowercase:D
  {
    \group_end:
    \NewDocumentCommand \Qux { >{ \SplitArgument { 2 } { ? } } m m }
  }
{ \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2] }

\group_begin:
\use:x
  {
    \group_end:
    \NewDocumentCommand \exp_not:N \Blah
      { >{\SplitArgument { 2 } { \tl_to_str:n { ; } } } m m }
  }
{ \__erw_foo:nnn #1 [#2] }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Foo{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\Qux{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\Blah{a,b;c,d;e}{f}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]